# Solve $\sin x-\cos x-4\cos^2 x \sin x=4\sin^2 x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Solve the equation

> > $\sin x-\cos x-4\cos^2 x \sin x=4\sin^2 x$

My attempt:

I have rewritten the equation as:
$$\sin x=\frac{4\cos ^2 x-\cos x-4}{4\cos^2 x-1}$$

I tried drawing graphs of LHS and RHS. But is there any analytical way?

Comment: What is the context? Do you have reason to believe there is an analytical solution?

Comment: Your question is meaningless. Just by seeing equation how can i know that there is no analytical solution.

Comment: If you got the equation from a textbook, and the chapter was about solving certain equations analytically, you would have added context to believe that such a solution was possible. If it was generated at random, then such a solution is likely not possible. So I ask again, what is the context for the problem?

Comment: I can rework it as a cubic in $\sin x$ with one $\cos x$ term left over... The context of the problem would definitely be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the half-angle substitution: $t = \tan(x/2)$. Then the following relations hold:
\begin{align*}
\cos(x) &= \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} \\
\sin(x) &= \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}.
\end{align*}
Then the equation becomes:
$$\frac{2t}{1 + t^2} - \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} - 8 \frac{t(1 - t^2)^2}{(1 + t^2)^3} = 16\frac{t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2}.$$
Multiplying both sides by $(1 + t^2)^3$, we get
$$(t^2 - 2t - 1)(1 + t^2)^2 - 8t(1 - t^2)^2 = 16t^2(1 + t^2).$$
When we expand and simplify, we get
$$t^6 - 10 t^5 - 15 t^4 + 12 t^3 - 17 t^2 - 10 t - 1 = 0.$$
Wolfram Alpha gives no elementary factors or roots, with two being non-real complex conjugates. But, if $t$ is a root of the above polynomial, then $x = 2\tan^{-1}(t)$ will be one such solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, so that $\cos(x)=(\omega+\omega^{-1})/2$ and $\sin(x)=(\omega-\omega^{-1})/2i$.  Then the equation we are trying to solve, when expressed in terms of $\omega$ and simplified is:
$$\frac{i\omega^6+2\omega^5-\omega^4-4\omega^3-\omega^2+2\omega-i}{2\omega^3}=0.$$

Unfortunately, there are no obvious factors to this equation, although wolfram alpha suggests that 3 of the 6 complex roots are of length 1, which means they correspond to actual solutions to the original problem.